# Обновление статичного файла

Tags: php

У меня есть статичный файл (zip), который обновляется по крону, в тоже время есть апи через которое может идти сотни запросов на его скачивание (по прямому url, типа site.com/file.zip). Как правильно заменять этот файл на новый что бы никто из клиентов в какой-то момент времени не получил битые данные?

Comment: ну закачай с другим именем, а потом rename

Comment: @Jean-Claude а если старый в этот момент качают?

Comment: Наверное лучше создать виртуальную ссылку (например используя банальный redirect). Каждый раз создавать новый ZIP с уникальным именем и как только он будет создан перенапрявлять ссылку на новый файл. Старые файлы удалять, когда они перестанут быть актуальными через некоторое время (так как их еще могут качать). А если нужен именно постояный URL (не редирект), то можно сделать постоянную виртуальную ссылку в файле htaccess (который нужно будет каждый раз обновлять после создания нового ZIP).

Answer (score 0):

Организуйте файл, который будет выдавать этот zip вместо прямой ссылки
например http://url/zip.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.xip"'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    if(is_writable('/путь до файла zip относительно положения zip.php'))
    {
        $ct=file_get_contents('/путь до файла zip относительно положения zip.php');
        echo $ct;
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```